# Interactive Grid- Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

When I am entering emp code in interactive grid region, automatically duplicate record created.
Please let me know how do I fix my issue.

I have entered emp code 1234,but automaticaly two duplicate report created.

I didn't found any relatable solution

Comment: If you created interactive grid with **wizard**, everything would work just fine. Therefore, I presume you modified something, somewhere. What was it? If you can't find the culprit, create a new interactive grid page (for the same table) and then compare two pages - old and new - to spot the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours in my IG .
**Note :** one of columns in my IG had LOV on it.
And that problem caused by that LOV !
**My Lov returns same id's for some records and that duplicate my records in IG** though in table I didn't have duplicate records but I see them in IG.
Describe your Table and your columns in IG that could make your problem more clear to us